# "Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this"(Visual Studio Code)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

****EDIT:** solved it by opening Android Studio, going to Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools and checking "Android SDK Command-line Tools". Rerunning "flutter doctor" in VS Code didn't give any complaints.**

I'm trying to finish the flutter installation but when I run `flutter doctor`, I get *Android license status unknown* *- Run* `flutter doctor --android-licenses`  *to accept the SDK licenses.*

When I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`  I get *Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.*
The editor I'm using is Visual Studio Code, and I've searched for this problem but it seems like most solutions are specific to Android Studio.

[Output from flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNvbi.png)

What I have tried is to download `cmdline-tools`
from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) and manually add it to `\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` but it didn't fix the problem. It's also asking me to "Update to the latest Android SDK" but how do I check which version I have and what the latest one is?

Answer (score 0):

open your android studio/ go to the sdk manager from tools above/ select android sdk and choose the command line tools to download/ then try doctor.

Comment: Seems like the correct answer here. A bit more details and better formatting would have been nice. Keep up the good work. :-)

Answer (score -1):

as told by the result of flutter doctor, you need to run the command  `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. This will ask you to accept terms and conditions to use the SDK then you'll be set to go.

Comment: It didn't ask me to accept terms and conditions. Instead I got "Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this"

Comment: Could you please carefully read your flutter doctor result please ? It is widely written Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`